# Cannot quit PhantomJS, windows 7. Phantom JS Version 2.1.1

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

Seems this bug came up briefly during Phantom JS version 2.48 from what I've seen, but I dont understand why it is present in the older (stable) version I am using.

Here is a very similar question.

[How to properly stop phantomjs execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25110624/how-to-properly-stop-phantomjs-execution)

However here is my code, and the error it throws

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS() # or add to your PATH
driver.set_window_size(1024, 768) # optional
driver.get('https://google.com/')

driver.close()
driver.quit()
```

Ive used both .close() and .quit() individually and together. close() seems to work by itself, but does not actually stop the phantomjs process.

driver.quit() gives me the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\test.py", line 9, in <module>
    driver.quit()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\phantomjs\webdriver.py", line 74, in quit
    self.service.stop()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 124, in stop
    self.process.stdout.close()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'close'
```

Any ideas or suggestions would be great. 
Thanks!

edit: I have also tried a reboot as stated here [Selenium webdriver + PhantomJS processes not closing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26868492/selenium-webdriver-phantomjs-processes-not-closing)

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion: check service.py patch:

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/1854

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/e85c59460b7292046f377b405882454c77458b96