# Python - Selenium PhantomJS - JSON Error

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I have a small test python script that uses Selenium and PhantomJS. Python version is 2.7 and PhantomJS is 1.9.2. I later plan to use this with BeautifulSoup for accessing a financial website.

My python script looks like this -

```
from selenium import webdriver
phantomJSPath = "C:\my working dir\\Lib\phantomjs.exe"
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=phantomJSPath)
```

After executing I get the below error -

File "C:\my working dir\Test.py", line 32, in run

```
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=phantomJSPath)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-   packages\selenium\webdriver\phantomjs\webdriver.py", line 56, in __init__
desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-  packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 87, in __init__
self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 136, in   start_session
'desiredCapabilities': desired_capabilities,
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 196, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 102, in check_response
value = json.loads(value_json)
File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 326, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 366, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end()) 
File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Would anyone know why I am getting this error?

Comment: PhantomJS 1.9.2 is really old and there may be an issue with an incompatibility with GhostDriver and the selenium library. Try to update to a newer PhantomJS version like 2.0.0, 1.9.8 or 1.9.7.

Comment: Which version of Selenium are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to answer my own bounty, but for those who might possibly run into similar issues: the http_proxy environment variable does not play well with phantomjs and selenium.  I removed it and all worked as it should have.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar issue (transient) when calling browser.close() with selenium 1.9.8 running on Ubunto 15:

```
  File "propertunity/soup/Soup.py", line 121, in get...
    browser.close()
  File "/home/<user>/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 473, in close
    self.execute(Command.CLOSE)
  File "/home/<user>/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 201, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/<user>/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 102, in check_response
    value = json.loads(value_json)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

There seem to be a known [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25110624/how-to-properly-stop-phantomjs-execution) with close() not really cleaning up after you finish with the browser. Try changing the close() to quit and setting the browser object to None.

Comment: In reference to the above bounty, this does not appear to be the same issue (exactly).

Answer (score 1):

You should give extra paramters to define `browser`, it tries to assign `desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities` which expects a json object. You can do it like following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
phantomJSPath = "C:\my working dir\\Lib\phantomjs.exe"
desiredCap = {'platform': 'ANY', 'browserName': 'phantomjs', 'version': '', 'javascriptEnabled': True}
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=phantomJSPath, port=0, desired_capabilities=desiredCap)
```

Comment: I think there is already a default to `desired_capabilities` which is a dictionary.