# phantomjs is not closing the process

Tags: c#, phantomjs

I'm trying to test some things with `PhantomJS` (v 2.0) in `C#` and is not closing it properly, which causing that my machine uses the 100% of the CPU.

All the program is working fine, except the part to close it.

i tried with

```
driver.Dispose();
driver.Quit();
driver.Close();
```

and (all of them)

```
Enviroment.Exit(-1);
Enviroment.Exit(0);
Enviroment.Exit(1);
return;
```

but the process still in the task manager

i tried to close the console brutally

```
 Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
```

but still not working.

there is the message that phantom shows to me in the console

```
[INFO  - 2015-10-19T09:43:58.542Z] GhostDriver - Main - running on port 62810
[INFO  - 2015-10-19T09:44:17.480Z] Session [f7138220-7645-11e5-b667-c72dd4c4644c
] - page.settings - {"XSSAuditingEnabled":false,"javascriptCanCloseWindows":true
,"javascriptCanOpenWindows":true,"javascriptEnabled":true,"loadImages":true,"loc
alToRemoteUrlAccessEnabled":false,"userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW6
4) AppleWebKit/538.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) PhantomJS/2.0.0 Safari/538.1","webSecur
ityEnabled":true}
[INFO  - 2015-10-19T09:44:17.499Z] Session [f7138220-7645-11e5-b667-c72dd4c4644c
] - page.customHeaders:  - {}
[INFO  - 2015-10-19T09:44:17.507Z] Session [f7138220-7645-11e5-b667-c72dd4c4644c
] - Session.negotiatedCapabilities - {"browserName":"phantomjs","version":"2.0.0
","driverName":"ghostdriver","driverVersion":"1.2.0","platform":"windows-7-32bit
","javascriptEnabled":true,"takesScreenshot":true,"handlesAlerts":false,"databas
eEnabled":false,"locationContextEnabled":false,"applicationCacheEnabled":false,"
browserConnectionEnabled":false,"cssSelectorsEnabled":true,"webStorageEnabled":f
alse,"rotatable":false,"acceptSslCerts":false,"nativeEvents":true,"proxy":{"prox
yType":"direct"}}
[INFO  - 2015-10-19T09:44:17.530Z] SessionManagerReqHand - _postNewSessionComman
d - New Session Created: f7138220-7645-11e5-b667-c72dd4c4644c
[INFO  - 2015-10-19T09:45:27.620Z] ShutdownReqHand - _handle - About to shutdown
```

in addition, i'm using selenium, but i don't think that there is an important information.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, this seems to be a common issue. See [this](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/issues/162) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25110624/how-to-properly-stop-phantomjs-execution).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I was able to solve this using Selenium WebDriver and PhantomJS.

```
var service = PhantomJSDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
try
{
    driver = new PhantomJSDriver(service);
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    service.Dispose();
}
finally
{
    service.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Possible Solution**

I'm not going to mark it as valid because is temporal, but for now, the easiest/Fastest way to solve the problem is get the process and kill it manually.

Why is not the best solution, because is going to **kill ALL PhantomJS process**, in my case there is only one, then is valid, but is better than lock the server.

```
foreach (Process proc in Process.GetProcessesByName("PhantomJS"))
{
    proc.Kill();
}
```

if anyone knows a way to get a specific process (if there are more than one) will be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this seems to work well in this scenario:

```
        //Close Driver
    driver.Close();

    // Get the current process.
    System.Diagnostics.Process myProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess(); 

    // Close process by sending a close message to its main window.
    myProcess.CloseMainWindow();

    // Free resources associated with process.
    myProcess.Close();

    Environment.Exit(0);
```