# Python Selenium PhantomJS quit() error

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I have limited space on my machine. So, I am running a loop that goes to a website, logs in, follows a link and scrapes data. To limit the space being used, I call a function that closes and quits the webdriver. Then I open a new one, log in again and follow a different link. After 3 or 4 times I get the error when I call the driver.quit().

```
def close_driver(driver):
  driver.close()
  driver.quit()
  return
```

I haven't had this issue on my Mac but when I try to run it on IBM bluemix. I get the error:

```
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes `PhantomJS` can run into these errors trying to close an instance that has already been closed. Instead of running both `close()` and `quit()`, just run `quit()`. `quit()` will do all necessary functions to properly close and exit the `webdriver` instance.

Comment: I have the same problem, without using `driver.close()` but just `driver.quit()`. It seems there is a bug in the `quit` method. see https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium/issues/3216

Comment: @TimotheusPokorra thouse should be resolved when you update your Selenium package to the newest version

Comment: @TimotheusPokorra @crookedleaf  I tried doing just `driver.quit()` . But it had the same result. I found a solution that worked for me via: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25110624/how-to-properly-stop-phantomjs-execution  Thanks to @leekaiinthesky  `import signal driver.service.process.send_signal(signal.SIGTERM)  # kill the specific phantomjs child proc  driver.quit()  # quit the node proc`

Comment: @LostPuppy this is actually pretty bad practice, but if it works, it works lol. Is your Selenium installation up to date? If so, running just `driver.quit()` should be sufficient. If it isn't up to date, and you are able to update it (it wont break anything), i'd highly recommend updating it.

Comment: @LostPuppy: I finally realized that my code was calling driver.quit() twice, which explains my issue. thanks for the hints!